# MySQL UPDATE different fields depending on values

Tags: mysql, case

I can't seem to get the following SQL code working:

```
    UPDATE ip_port
    SET 
    enabled = (case when fails > 5 then enabled = 0 else enabled end),
    fails = (case when fails < 5 then fails = fails + 1 else fails end)
    WHERE
    proxy LIKE '%1.2.3.4:8080%'
```

Basically I'm trying to get the code to set `enabled = 0` if `fails > 5`, or if `fails < 5` then add 1 to fails.

The first part of the query works in that it sets enabled to 0 if fails is 6, but the increment on fails is not working

Comment: Just remove the "`enabled =`" and "`fails =`" from the THEN clauses. Let the CASE expressions return "`0`" and "`fails+1`". Everything else looks right. Except, some other statement is going to need to make the "jump" of the fails value from 5 to 6. This statement will only increment "fails" up to a maximum value of 5. (Fencepost error? ` fails <= 5` ? `fails >= 5` ? )

Comment: Thanks, yeah I spotted that one just before putting the code live. Could have been embarrasing :)

Comment: That's why we test, James, that's why we test. (I don't know the requirements, but it looks suspiciously like you might want `fails` to be increased by 1, no matter the current value of `fails`. But you know the requirements, I'm just guessing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE ip_port
SET enabled = case when fails > 5 
                   then 0 
                   else enabled 
              end,
    fails = case when fails < 5 
                 then fails + 1 
                 else fails 
            end
WHERE proxy LIKE '%1.2.3.4:8080%'
```

Comment: You should remove the `=` before the `0`.

Comment: Thank you both of you. It's been bugging me so much!!